# Repeating all month from first table with data from second table including null months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to combine 2 table with same column but different ID depends on months. Repeat the first table based on new ID with month column then make null for data that are not existing. I tried this query but it just putting ID 2 in the same month from ID 1.

```
SELECT
  a.month, b.month
FROM
  all_month a
LEFT JOIN
  billing   b
    ON a.month = b.month
```

| FIRST TABLE | SECOND TABLE | SECOND TABLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MONTH | ID | MONTH |
| JANUARY | 1 | JANUARY |
| FEBRAURY | 1 | FEBRAURY |
| MARCH | 2 | JANUARY |
| APRIL | 2 | DECEMBER |
| MAY |  |  |
| JUNE |  |  |
| JULY |  |  |
| AUGUST |  |  |
| SEPTEMBER |  |  |
| OCTOBER |  |  |
| NOVEMBER |  |  |
| DECEMBER |  |  |

EXPECTED RESULT

| MONTH | ID | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JANUARY | 1 | JANUARY |
| FEBRAURY | 1 | FEBRAURY |
| MARCH | NULL | NULL |
| APRIL | NULL | NULL |
| MAY | NULL | NULL |
| JUNE | NULL | NULL |
| JULY | NULL | NULL |
| AUGUST | NULL | NULL |
| SEPTEMBER | NULL | NULL |
| OCTOBER | NULL | NULL |
| NOVEMBER | NULL | NULL |
| DECEMBER | 1 | DECEMBER |
| JANUARY | 2 | JANUARY |
| FEBRAURY | NULL | NULL |
| MARCH | NULL | NULL |
| APRIL | NULL | NULL |
| MAY | NULL | NULL |
| JUNE | NULL | NULL |
| JULY | NULL | NULL |
| AUGUST | NULL | NULL |
| SEPTEMBER | NULL | NULL |
| OCTOBER | NULL | NULL |
| NOVEMBER | NULL | NULL |
| DECEMBER | 2 | DECEMBER |

Comment: What does "first table second table" mean? Why aren't you showing each table individually?  Perhaps read [mre]? (Hint; don't use "...", use concrete examples in full...)

Comment: Hi, that’s so easy to understand. In the first table i have month name for a year just 12 months and link with the month to second table.

Comment: Edited to more detailed question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get what you are asking. Provided I get your tables the following will work.

Select your ids from the billing table -- then left join your months to them and then join your billing.

Remove the counts.sectionId from the select -- just for demo purposes to illustrate how it works.

```
SELECT
    --counts.sectionId,
    m.month,
    b.Id,
    b.month 
FROM (
    select distinct id from #tmp_Billing
) as counts(sectionId)
OUTER APPLY #tmp_Months m 
LEFT JOIN #tmp_Billing b ON m.month = b.month AND counts.sectionId = b.id
ORDER BY
    sectionId, 
    MONTH(m.month + ' 1 2000'),
    b.Id
```

Sample Data:

```
SELECT 
    *
INTO #tmp_Months
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('January'),
        ('February'),
        ('March'),
        ('April'),
        ('May'),
        ('June'),
        ('July'),
        ('August'),
        ('September'),
        ('October'),
        ('November'),
        ('December')
) AS m(month)


SELECT 
    *
INTO #tmp_Billing
FROM (
    VALUES
        (1, 'January'),
        (2, 'January'),
        (1, 'February'),
        (2, 'February'),
        (1, 'December'),
        (2, 'December')
) AS m(Id, month)
```

Results:

| month | Id | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | 1 | January |
| February | 1 | February |
| March | NULL | NULL |
| April | NULL | NULL |
| May | NULL | NULL |
| June | NULL | NULL |
| July | NULL | NULL |
| August | NULL | NULL |
| September | NULL | NULL |
| October | NULL | NULL |
| November | NULL | NULL |
| December | NULL | NULL |
| January | 2 | January |
| February | 2 | February |
| March | NULL | NULL |
| April | NULL | NULL |
| May | NULL | NULL |
| June | NULL | NULL |
| July | NULL | NULL |
| August | NULL | NULL |
| September | NULL | NULL |
| October | NULL | NULL |
| November | NULL | NULL |
| December | 2 | December |

**Edit**:
If the ID is a client ID, you can sub out the client table in the query. Then you get a more semantic meaning. For my clients, grab months and billing data for them.

Also, the link from @MatBailie has some good points in it.

Comment: Hi, Tested it but the month from second is just repeating from the first table whole years month then keep repeating depends on how many months I had in second table. How can i fix it? I already edit the question to more detailed. Thank you

Comment: Do the results I am showing match what you expect? I just copy and pasted my example in SSMS and produced the full list you are showing.

Comment: Hey your query works fine. Thank you. This answer what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, Do you any chance know if I wanted to show only all february?

Comment: Add a where statement -- WHERE m.month = 'February'

Comment: I wanted to contain all the details and it just showing the February month.

Comment: I think I misunderstood -- try this.  On the billing join: and b.month = 'february'

Comment: Nevermind I actually use that for crystal report and I just suppress the column if it is not equal to the month. Big Thanks! Cheers